# Issue with javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a issue with javascript. Please take a look:

```
    function Component(data)
    {
       var self = this;

       self.Name = data.name;
    }

    function Testing() {
        var self = this;

        self.Components = [
        {
            A: new Component({
                name: 'test1'
            })
        }, {
            B: new Component({
                name: 'test2'
            })
        }, {
            C: new Component({
                name: 'test3'
            })
        }];
    }
```

Now what i am trying to do is, I want to access each component from Components array by its property name (A, B ,C ...). So for this i did and getting error:

```
var t = new Testing();

t.Components['A'].Name; ==> //Error: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
```

Whats the issue ?

Comment: Without changing the structure, you have an array of objects, so you'd have to access the values with `t.Components[0]['A'].Name`, `t.Components[1]['B'].Name`, etc. But using an object instead of an array of objects makes more sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the properties of `Component` using a key `self.Components` must be an object (associative array).  The code attempts to access the array using a `key`, which is fine for associative arrays, but will not work for a regular array as declared in the code. Switching `self.Components` to an object literal will allow the properties to be accessed by key.

```
function Testing() {
    var self = this;

    self.Components = {

        A: new Component({
            name: 'test1'
        }), 
        B: new Component({
            name: 'test2'
        }), 
        C: new Component({
            name: 'test3'
        })
    };
}
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/fxfbe/

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for picking up those syntax errors.  Just woke up a few minutes ago!

Comment: @ Kevin: Not a problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Components` defined in the `Testing` is an array, remove array and create simply as object..

```
function Testing() {
....
    self.Components = {
        A: new Component({
            name: 'test1'
        }),
        B: new Component({
            name: 'test2'
        }),
        C: new Component({
            name: 'test3'
        })
    };
}
```